# Discontinuities of stochastically continuous Gaussian process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Can a stochastically continuous Gaussian process have essential discontinuities (non-jump)?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: I hope no :) . I think it should be jumps only.

Comment: But **why** do you think so? Mathematical reasons, please.

Comment: If there is an essential discontinuity at $t$, then either left or right sided limit doesn't exist at $X_t(w)$. So there exist an $\varepsilon>0 $ and  points $s$ arbitrarily close to $t$ such that $|X_t(\omega)-X_s(\omega)|\geq\varepsilon.$ It seems like stochastic continuity doesn't really exclude that...

Comment: "Stochastic continuity" is a continuity with respect to convergence in probability, or so I thought. Your last comment seems to address almost sure continuity (of the paths $t\mapsto X_t(\omega)$). Could you clarify?

Comment: yes, its continuity in probability. Stochastic continuity says that the probability of $\{|X_t−X_s|≥ε\}$ goes to zero as $s\rightarrow t,$ but still, this event can occur infinitely often (for infinitely many $s$) for some sample paths. If there was almost sure continuity, then it should happen only finitely often with probability 1.

Comment: well, but when I think about it, I think there is still something missing in my consideration. Because infinitely often farther away then $\varepsilon$ from $X_t$ might be a jump. It doesn't characterize essential discontinuity precizelly enough....